# custom option template for select tag (angular 8.x)

Tags: angular

I have Angular 8 app
So html in my component:

```
<select class="form-control" id="theme" formControlName="theme" (change)="onChangeTheme($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of themeItems" [value]="item.id">
        <i class="fa fa-circle text-{{item.id}} pr-2"></i>
        <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
    </option>
</select>
```

And I want to populate custom template as above. `ngx-select-dropdown` supports this feature? Maybe I can do custom option template without any plugins? Or what's plugin the best match for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider the [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) library. It supports custom templates too. You may refer to the documentation for custom templates over [here](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates).